# Reading the similar data from more than two collections in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am novice user to MongoDB. In our application the data size for each table quite bit large, So I decided to split the same into different collections even though it is same of kind. The only difference is the "id" between each document(documents in one collection is under one category) in the all the collections. So we decided to insert the data into number collections and each collections will be having certain number of documents. currently I have 10 collections of same of kind of document data.
My requirement is 
1) to get the data from all the collections in a single query to display in application home page.
2) I do need to get the data by using sorting and filtering before fetching.

I have gone through some of the posts in the stackoverflow saying that use Mongo-3.2 **$lookup** aggregation for this requirement. but I am suspecting If I use $lookup for 10 collections, there might be performance Issue and too complex query.
since I have divided the my same kind of data into number of collections(Each collection will have the documents which comes under one category, Like that I have the 10 categories, so I need to use 10 collections).

Could any body please suggest me whether my approach is correct?

Comment: If the reason you are splitting the collections because of large data size, you should have used [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) instead to distribute load/size.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot data, how could you display all of them in a webpage?

My understanding is that you will only display a portion of the dataset by querying the database. Since you didn't mention how many records you have, it's not easy to make a recommendation.

Based on the vague description, sharding is the solution, you should check out the [official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/).

However, before you do sharding, and since you mentioned are a novice user, you probably want to check your databases' indexing, data models, and benchmark your performance first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should store all 10 types of data in 1 collection, not 10. Don't make things more difficult than they need to be.

Comment: Yes thats correct helmy, but the data will be huge, For one collection it will be huge.

Comment: Define "huge"? It does not matter, you should not split up collections like that based solely on the amount of data. As Wan mentioned, sharding would be the approach in for dealing with scaling.

Comment: Can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455609/getting-the-required-documents-from-both-the-collections-in-one-query-in-mongodb/38456140?noredirect=1#comment64318284_38456140      This meets exactly my requirement

Comment: I can look at it, but I am telling you that you are taking the wrong approach by splitting the data into 10 collections. You are going to cause your self more performance and development headaches than you are solving.

Comment: Okay helmy, Thank you. Please look at the link and please let me know if it is possible