# Getting the required documents from both the collections in one query in MongoDB-3.2.7

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have two collections like below in MongoDB.

## lookupcol1

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sku" : "abc", description: "product 1", "instock" : 120, "groupId":100100},
{ "_id" : 2, "sku" : "def", description: "product 2", "instock" : 80,"groupId":100100 },
{ "_id" : 3, "sku" : "ijk", description: "product 3", "instock" : 60 },
{ "_id" : 4, "sku" : "jkl",description: "product 4", "instock" : 70 },
{ "_id" : 5, "sku": null, description: "Incomplete", "groupId":100100 },
{ "_id" : 6 }
```

## lookupcol2

```
{ "_id" : 12, "sku" : "bcd", description: "product 2", "instock" : 121, "groupId":100100},
{ "_id" : 23, "sku" : "def", description: "product 2", "instock" : 810, "groupId":100100},
{ "_id" : 34, "sku" : "ijk", description: "product 3", "instock" : 60,"groupId":100100 },
{ "_id" : 45, "sku" : "jkl",description: "product 4", "instock" : 70 },
{ "_id" : 56, "sku": "def", description: "Incomplete","groupId":100100 },
{ "_id" : 67, "groupId":100100}
```

I want to fetch the documents from both the collections which has "groupId" as 100100.

The expected result should be shown below.

Result:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sku" : "abc", description: "product 1", "instock" : 120, "groupId":100100},
{ "_id" : 2, "sku" : "def", description: "product 2", "instock" : 80,"groupId":100100 },
{ "_id" : 5, "sku": null, description: "Incomplete", "groupId":100100 },
{ "_id" : 12, "sku" : "bcd", description: "product 2", "instock" : 121, "groupId":100100},
{ "_id" : 23, "sku" : "def", description: "product 2", "instock" : 810, "groupId":100100},
{ "_id" : 34, "sku" : "ijk", description: "product 3", "instock" : 60,"groupId":100100 },
{ "_id" : 56, "sku": "def", description: "Incomplete","groupId":100100 },
{ "_id" : 67, "groupId":100100}
```

Could any body please tell me how to get above output.

Comment: have you considered merging all the collections into one?

Comment: Yes I considered but I want to know both the approaches.

Comment: In MongoDB, we cannot do joins like in SQL. Another approach would be from the driver/application end; make a getByGroupId for each collection and then make a getByGroupID which uses all the others and returns your desired result.  I have heard there is a $lookup (aggregation) in the newest version but I have no knowledge of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = {groupId: 100100};
var r1 = db.lookupcol1.find(q);
var r2 = db.lookupcol2.find(q);
r1.concat(r2);
```

Comment: Hello @Amiram, I want the entire result in one query

Comment: You can do it with aggregation with $setUnion but this is complicated. Why not query twice?

Comment: Thank you @Amiram, I have given only 2 collections in the above example but I need to collect the data from 20 collections like baove. So I need to query 20 times in that case.

Comment: I don't think you can do it as far as I know

Comment: Can I use $setUnion for this?

Comment: I'm not sure. Looks like you can't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117698/discussion-between-user-and-amiram-korach).